# Query for records where a column is not nil in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In code:

```
<% @hotelUser=HotelUser.find( cookies[:user_id2]) %>

<%= debug @orderLast=Order.where(:email=>@hotelUser.email,"order.hotel_user_id IS NOT NULL").last%>
```

I am getting syntax error after executing this code.I want to search `hotel_user_id` where `hotel_user_id != nil or empty?`. Please tell me the right syntax.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
Order.where(email: @hotelUser.email).where.not(hotel_user_id: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this

```
Order.where(email: @hotelUser.email).where("hotel_user_id <> ?", nil)
```

Comment: `where("hotel_user_id <> ?", nil)` will not generate the correct SQL. `<> NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` are different things.